# Get service status in c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, service

in my c++ application in linux how can I get a service status (like service abc status in terminal when the abc is the service)

thanks

Comment: You don't want to do that. Both the way serivces are started and *their names* are installation-dependent. What is your ultimate goal with this?

Answer (score 3):

```
FILE * f = popen("service abc status", "r");
```

Then read from f with e.g. fgets

```
char Line[100];
while (fgets(Line, 100, f) != NULL)
    cout << Line;
```

Remember to close the file:

```
int st = pclose(f);
```

Then you can check the exit code and such using the macros described in "man 2 wait" on `st`

Comment: I want to get the status by a code not to perform service status

Comment: service status is dependent on your distribution and setup. You'll need to either duplicate what the `service` application/script does, or run it and parse output.

Comment: and if I want to do it without a system call?

Comment: Then you look at *your* distributions service application, see how that handles the status parameter, and duplicate exactly what it does in your code. There's simply no generic way of doing this, it is specific to the distribution. My preferred distribution don't even *have* a service command.

Comment: @Erik Thanks for pointing out the `popen()` command. Very useful and I never knew it existed!